# ANSYS Mechanical Contact behavior

Tags: mechanical-engineering, ansys

I am working on ANSYS Mechanical. As i was reading the user's guide i saw a section about contact behavior. Symmetric and asymmetric. Can someone explain me on this? How to use these contacts?

Comment: For rigid-flex contact you need to set it as asymmetrical. Otherwise keep it program controlled (symmetric).

Answer (score 1):

Just look into the help pages (`C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v172\commonfiles\help\en-us\help\wb_sim\ds_Contact_Definition.html`).

A contact object in ANSYS consists of a contact and a target object.

[image: pic]

When a contact region is defined in Workbench two contact objects are created (symmetric contact), one as seen above, and the other with the contact/target geometries flipped. This is default (program controlled).

Only when a flexible body is in contact with a rigid body the above behavior does not apply and an asymmetric behavior is needed. In this case there is only one target and one contact surface (I think target is on rigid body only).

Comment: Actually i read the documentation regarding contacts. But i can't understand is in assymetrical contact can be peneterated by the target but it would not penetrate the target itself. So i am unable to get my head around this.